# Symfony 2.8 FOSUserBundle delete cookies on logout

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to delete some extra cookies when user logs out.
How do I do that?

[image]

I have that in my config.yml

```
logout:
            path: /logout
            handlers: [logout_handler]
            delete_cookies:
                c_user: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                sb: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                xs: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                fr: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                pl: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                lu: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                datr: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                dats: { path: /, domain: .facebook.com }
                pnl_data: { path: /, domain: www.facebook.com }
```

But that "delete_cookies" option doesn't work.
I also have the logout handler in case that help. I don't really know what to write there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have your configuration in the *security.yml* file under the one of your firewall sections, and checkout the [full security configuration for 2.8](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) as reference:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        somename:
            logout:
                delete_cookies:
                    a: { path: null, domain: null }
                    b: { path: null, domain: null }
                handlers: [some.service.id, another.service.id]
                success_handler: some.service.id
            anonymous: ~
```

As you mentioned in the logout success handler you can do some additional processing:

> If you need to do something more interesting after logging out, you
>   can specify a logout success handler by adding a success_handler key
>   and pointing it to a service id of a class that implements
>   LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface. See Security Configuration Reference.

Check out the `\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\CookieClearingLogoutHandler` which deletes all the requested cookies via the response headers

```
/**
 * Implementation for the LogoutHandlerInterface. Deletes all requested cookies.
 *
 * @param Request        $request
 * @param Response       $response
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 */
public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
{
    foreach ($this->cookies as $cookieName => $cookieData) {
        $response->headers->clearCookie($cookieName, $cookieData['path'], $cookieData['domain']);
    }
}
```

So inside your handler you could do something like:

```
$response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
$response->headers->clearCookie('nameOfTheCookie');
$response->send();
```